# asp.net core mvc route renders querystring, but I don't want that

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-routing

I am using the default route in an ASP.NET CORE MVC 2.0 Project:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

I have a hyper link like follows:

```
<a asp-controller="Services" asp-action="Information" asp-route-id="Gardens" class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary">Find out more</a>
```

it produces the following path at run-time:

```
services/information?id=Gardens
```

but I want:

```
services/information/gardens
```

Comment: Does it do the same thing with attribute routing

Comment: I can't reproduce the behaviour with the settings and sample code you provided. If you start a fresh project and just paste you <a..> tag somewhere do you get the same behaviour?

Comment: I tried attribute routing and it does the same thing. I am using dotnetcore 2.0. Even if I create a manual hyperlink it wont recognize it unless I append the querystring. ?id=Gardens as opposed to /Gardens